# Numpy slower than Mathematica?

Tags: numpy, performance, optimization

This is a continuation of a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/290726/performance-of-polynomial-functions-in-mathematica-vs-python?noredirect=1#comment722983_290726) The data is `floatMatrix` which has dimensions (750000, 4). The function `testFunction[x,y,w,z]` is a polynomial function of 4 variables that returns a 4D vector and is meant to be applied to all of the 750000 vectors.

For Mathematica, I am using a listable `Compile` with `Parallelization->False`.

```
 Compile[{{f, _Real, 1}}, 
 {
   {0.011904761904761973` f[[2]]f[[1]]^3 + 
    0.002976190476190474` f[[1]]f[[2]]^3 - 0.020833333333333325` f[[3]] + 
    0.002976190476190474` f[[3]]^3 + 
    f[[2]]^2 (0.0029761904761904778` f[[3]] +...
   {0.002976190476190483` f[[1]]^3 + 0.011904761904761906` f[[2]]^3 - 
    0.0875` f[[3]] + 0.0029761904761904765` f[[3]]^3 + 
    f[[1]]^2 (0.005952380952380952` f[[2]] +...
 },CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True];

time = RepeatedTiming[testFunction[floatMatrix]];
Print["In Mathematica-C it takes an average of ", time[[1]], " secs."]
```

For Python I am using NumPy. I have two implementations:

Implementation 1 (transposing inside):

```py
def testFunction(data):
    f1, f2, f3, f4 = data.T
    
    results = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 4))  # Initialize a results array

    results[:, 0] = (0.011904761904761973*f2*f1**3 + 0.002976190476190474*f1*f2**3 - 
                    0.020833333333333325*f3 + 0.002976190476190474*f3**3 + f2**2* 
                    (0.0029761904761904778*f3 +...
    results[:, 1] = (0.002976190476190483*f1**3 + 0.011904761904761906*f2**3 - 0.0875*f3
                   + 0.0029761904761904765*f3**3 + f1**2*(0.005952380952380952*f2 + 
                     0.002976190476190469*f3 + 0.0029761904761904726*f4) +...
    return results

duration=0

for i in range(10):
    start_time = time.time()
    testFunction(floatMatrix)
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = duration + end_time - start_time

duration=duration*0.1

print(f"With numpy it takes an average of': {duration} seconds")
```

Implementation 2 (transposing outside):

```py
def testFunction(f1, f2, f3, f4):
    results = np.zeros((f1.shape[0], 4))  # Initialize a results array

    results[:, 0] = ...
    results[:, 1] = ...
    results[:, 2] = ...
    results[:, 3] = ...

    return results

# Transpose the data outside the function
f1, f2, f3, f4 = floatMatrix.T

duration=0

for i in range(10):
    start_time = time.time()
    testFunction(f1, f2, f3, f4)
    end_time = time.time()
    duration = duration + end_time - start_time

duration=duration*0.1

print(f"With numpy vectorized operations it takes an average of': {duration} seconds")
```

These are the times:

- Mathematica: 0.119938 seconds
- Numpy (tranposing inside): 0.206754 seconds
- Numpy (tranposing outside): 0.20789377 seconds

I was expecting NumPy to be much faster. Is there any changes I can make to the code in Python to make it faster than Mathematica compiled functions?

Comment: Can you provide complete, reproducible code? Have you verified that the Mathematica implementation and the Python implementation output the same results? If so, your question may be appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: In general, since `.T` creates views, not copies, your `f1,f2,f3,f4` will not be contiguous in memory. This will severely degrade performance.

Comment: you are calculating `f1**3` twice, cache result instead, same goes for `f3**3` and anything else you find

Comment: also, on my machine `array*array*array` is much faster than `array**3`. Check yourself

Comment: The small time difference between the 2 numpy tests tells us that the `f1,f2,...=data.T` step doesn't take much time, so it doesn't matter whether it's done once, or once per test.  The resulting `f1` etc arrays are `views` of the original, with the same memory layout in both cases.

Comment: Cross language timings don't tell us much about the languages, especially if one uses some sort of "compile" mode.  The numba answer doesn't tell us much about good numpy use either - it's essentially a "compile" mode, creating new code.   But if you like the numba speed, and aren't bothered by the extra coding work, great.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you could make this NumPy code faster. One would be to turn on Numba, which is an optimizer which uses a compiler to accelerate NumPy heavy code.

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def test_function():
    ...
```

Doing this, I get a 6x speedup.

Next, I tried turning on [fastmath](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/performance-tips.html#fastmath). This is a mode which allows Numba to alter certain floating point operations for speed. (For example, it is normally not allowed to rewrite (a+b)+c into a+(b+c), but under fastmath this is an allowed transformation.)

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True):
def test_function()
    ...
```

This gives a 3% speedup.

Next, I noticed that the order this computation is done in has poor memory locality relative to the order that Mathematica is doing it. Mathematica is computing one vector at a time, but NumPy is computing one component of your expression at a time, which requires it to, for example, load the `f1` column into memory multiple times.

To solve this, I introduced an explicit loop. (See code section for details.) This got me another 44% speedup.

Combining these optimizations, I get a 9.5x speedup versus the original Python implementation. (I did not benchmark the Mathematica code, as I don't have a copy.)

#### Code

Original (plus fixes to fix syntax errors)

```
floatMatrix = np.random.rand(1200000, 4)
def test_function_transpose_inside(data):
    f1, f2, f3, f4 = data.T
    
    results = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 4))  # Initialize a results array

    results[:, 0] = (0.011904761904761973*f2*f1**3 + 0.002976190476190474*f1*f2**3 - 
                    0.020833333333333325*f3 + 0.002976190476190474*f3**3 + f2**2* 
                    (0.0029761904761904778*f3))
    results[:, 1] = (0.002976190476190483*f1**3 + 0.011904761904761906*f2**3 - 0.0875*f3
                   + 0.0029761904761904765*f3**3 + f1**2*(0.005952380952380952*f2 + 
                     0.002976190476190469*f3 + 0.0029761904761904726*f4))
    return results
```

With Numba

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def test_function_numba(data):
    f1, f2, f3, f4 = data.T
    
    results = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 4))  # Initialize a results array

    results[:, 0] = (0.011904761904761973*f2*f1**3 + 0.002976190476190474*f1*f2**3 - 
                    0.020833333333333325*f3 + 0.002976190476190474*f3**3 + f2**2* 
                    (0.0029761904761904778*f3))
    results[:, 1] = (0.002976190476190483*f1**3 + 0.011904761904761906*f2**3 - 0.0875*f3
                   + 0.0029761904761904765*f3**3 + f1**2*(0.005952380952380952*f2 + 
                     0.002976190476190469*f3 + 0.0029761904761904726*f4))
    return results
```

Numba and fastmath

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def test_function_numba_fastmath(data):
    f1, f2, f3, f4 = data.T
    
    results = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 4))  # Initialize a results array

    results[:, 0] = (0.011904761904761973*f2*f1**3 + 0.002976190476190474*f1*f2**3 - 
                    0.020833333333333325*f3 + 0.002976190476190474*f3**3 + f2**2* 
                    (0.0029761904761904778*f3))
    results[:, 1] = (0.002976190476190483*f1**3 + 0.011904761904761906*f2**3 - 0.0875*f3
                   + 0.0029761904761904765*f3**3 + f1**2*(0.005952380952380952*f2 + 
                     0.002976190476190469*f3 + 0.0029761904761904726*f4))
    return results
```

Numba, fastmath and a loop

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def test_function_numba_loop(data):
    results = np.zeros((data.shape[0], 4))  # Initialize a results array
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        f1, f2, f3, f4 = data[i]
        results[i, 0] = (0.011904761904761973*f2*f1**3 + 0.002976190476190474*f1*f2**3 - 
                        0.020833333333333325*f3 + 0.002976190476190474*f3**3 + f2**2* 
                        (0.0029761904761904778*f3))
        results[i, 1] = (0.002976190476190483*f1**3 + 0.011904761904761906*f2**3 - 0.0875*f3
                       + 0.0029761904761904765*f3**3 + f1**2*(0.005952380952380952*f2 + 
                         0.002976190476190469*f3 + 0.0029761904761904726*f4))
    return results
```

#### Benchmark Results

```
%timeit test_function_transpose_inside(floatMatrix)
215 ms ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit test_function_numba(floatMatrix)
33.6 ms ± 344 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit test_function_numba_fastmath(floatMatrix)
32.6 ms ± 452 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit test_function_numba_loop(floatMatrix)
22.5 ms ± 68.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Further optimizations

If every element of `results` is written to at least once, you could replace `np.zeros((data.shape[0], 4))` with `np.empty((data.shape[0], 4))`. In my testing this got an additional 10% speedup.